# asp.net button_click function returns weird value for devexpress ASPxHiddenField

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a hidden field in my page:

```
 <dx:ASPxHiddenField ID="screenWidth" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  
 ClientInstanceName="screenWidth"></dx:ASPxHiddenField>
```

and I set its value using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#screenWidth").val($(window).width());
    var value = document.getElementById('screenWidth').value;
    alert(value);  
});
```

(the last two lines are used to debug, and the alert shows the correct value).

On the same page I have a button for resizing one of the controls, according to the windows size, and I am trying to get the screen size:

```
string screenWidth = Request.Form["screenHeight"].ToString();
```

But, when I click the button, I get this for the screeenWidth variable:

`{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;12|#|#&quot;}`

Request.Form["screenHeight"] returns the same string as above.

What am I doing wrong?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Devexpress framework has a dubious way (well, for me it's dubious) to handle their hidden field:
I had to set the window value to a new property of the hidden field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    screenWidth.Set('scW', $(window).width());
    alert(screenWidth.Get('scW'));
});
```

then, in the C# button_clik function I got the value this way:

```
string screenWidth1 = screenWidth["scW"].ToString();
```

This link helped:
[How to get a value by a key from ASPxHiddenField](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q315270)

Quote from the article:

> " The ASPxHiddenField component represents a dictionary that can
>   maintain an unlimited number of elements."

As Uranus suggested, this is stated in their documentation:
[ASPxHiddenField Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxHiddenFieldtopic)

Comment: Actually, storing a set of values of different type is the primary purpose of this component. This is clearly stated in the documentation. If you do not mind, I suggest that you add the [documentation link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxHiddenFieldtopic) to make your answer complete and useful for others.

Comment: you are correct, I added the link in the answer. I am pretty new to Devexpress...